# EditText Listener delay before execute again

Tags: android, delay, execute

I have problem with my app
It's crashing after spamming the EditText field
How can i add delay to the code before execute the "DoSearch"?

Ie, when the EditBox is edited the application have to idle for 1sec and listen if it's edited again
if true, wait another sec
if false, execute DoSearch

I hope you can understand my situation

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Searchfield);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        new DoSearch().execute();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:
ok i solved the problem
i define int searchCount as 0
everytime the TextEdit is changed it's called the delay handler
delay handler only execute DoSearch on the last delay handler call by checking  if searchCount  equal the last

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchCoupon);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        searchCount++;
        SearchHandler.sendMessageDelayed(SearchHandler.obtainMessage(searchCount), 1000);   
    }
}); 


private Handler SearchHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == searchCount) {
            new DoSearch().execute();
            System.out.println("Success" + searchCount + "=" + msg.what);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(msg.what + " - " + searchCount);
        }
    }
};
```

There is a place to improve this method ? or it's actually a effective way ?

Answer (score -1):

Add a [delayed Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29), and every time onTextchanged is called remove the previous message from the handler and keep posting with 1 second delay. If within one second ontextChanged is called then the previous Dosearch will be cancelled

Comment: the delay work, but it doesn't cancel the others and when the delay is over, the doSearch spam again... or i'm using it wrong

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean by spamming. but if it is crashing you can post the logcat output.

Comment: i solved the problem, There is a place to improve this method ? or it's actually a effective way ?